# Differences between Center and Median options of Blender snap target menu?

Tags: snapping

As title: what are the **differences** between the "Center" and "Median" snap target options?

The Blender manual explicates with pictures only one of the two options I'm trying to compare: the "Median":

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/precision/snap.html#snap-target

I use all the options them for a very long time and I know what they do but what I want to figure out is just what **differences** are there between the two options cause it seems to me that they behave exactly the same way.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Center uses the pivot point instead of a property of the object itself. The default for the pivot point, however, happens to just be the median center, which is why selecting "center" doesn't appear to do anything by default:

[image: pivot point menu]

In other words, you can think of the "center" setting as a "defer to pivot point" setting. The primary use of this is that it lets the snap point be defined by the 3D cursor by selecting "3D Cursor" in the pivot point menu (see above image) while the snap target is set to "Center". Using "Center" with the other pivot point options isn't too useful in most cases.

Comment: willy asking about the snap median and center not the pivot point

Comment: Thanks JtheNinja, I really appreciate the effort for your answer but the menu I'm talking about in the question (perhaps I'm wrong) is not the **Pivot Point** menu but the **Snap Target** menu: it is the one near the magnet...

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear: the "center" option in the "snap target" menu essentially is a "defer to pivot point menu" option. Whatever you set as the pivot point also becomes the snap target when in "center" mode.

Comment: @JtheNinja, no problem, nothing to be sorry about. This seems a little bit more clear: may I ask you to edit the answer with the comment and also by adding an example to completely clarify the point? Any way I'm doing some experiments my own and it seems that setting one or the other option in Snap Target menu affects the behavior only if I set 3D Cursor in Pivot Point menu. I know I'm bothering you, sorry... But I just want to be sure to really understand the matter... thanks so much.